# Unexpected "using" keyword after "@" character

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I run my code, I will see that error:

> Unexpected "using" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "using" with "@".

This is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Quests.Models.Entities.Diagram>

@if(Model.Select(x => x.Rank).Where(x => x == "Podstawowy").Count() > 0)
{
    Html.Partial("DiagramsTable", Model.Where(x => x.Rank == "Podstawowy"));
}
```

The error show, the `Html.Partial` generates a bug.
I tried many solutions and I can't find right.

From controller I'm sending model `IEnumerable<Diagram>`.

I can't see any "using" keyword in my code, it has 4 lines. That's complete.

My DiagramTable.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Quests.Models.Entities.Diagram>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">@Model.FirstOrDefault().Rank</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element</td>
                    <td>Poziom</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var diagram in Model)
                {
                    <tr class="@diagram.DiagramColorInfo()">
                        <td>@diagram.Element</td>
                        <td>@diagram.Level.ToString()</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (diagram.Have == false)
                            {
                                @using (Html.BeginForm("SetHave", "Diagram", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return confirm('Ustawić posiadanie schematu?');" }))
                                {
                                    @Html.Hidden("DiagramID", diagram.DiagramID)
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Zdobyto" />
                                }
                            }
                            else if ((diagram.Crafted == false) && (diagram.Have == true))
                            {
                                @using (Html.BeginForm("SetCrafted", "Diagram", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return confirm('Ustawić posiadanie schematu?');" }))
                                {
                                    @Html.Hidden("DiagramID", diagram.DiagramID)
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Stworzono" />
                                }
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is all of it?

Comment: can you post your DiagramsTable partial.

Comment: Yes thats all. I pasted DiagramTable partial

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error is coming from? You have a `@using` statement in your `DiagramTable.cshtml` page.

Comment: OMG. The debugger puts me in confusion. Of course its becouse in the partial view i used "using" keyword. Its already works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@` character from the following lines of code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetHave", "Diagram", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return confirm('Ustawić posiadanie schematu?');" })) 

@using (Html.BeginForm("SetCrafted", "Diagram", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return confirm('Ustawić posiadanie schematu?');" }))
```

When you get this error in Visual Studio all you have to do is **double click on it** and it will take you to the line of code which contains the unwanted `@` character:

[image: Visual Studio Error List]

Answer (score 1):

On most Razor notation operators you dont need to use another "@" inside the same scope.

```
@if(something)
{          
      @Html.Hidden("InputID", model.Field) // this will show an error, due the previous "@" of "@if"            
}
```

You can fix that by removing the following "@" operator inside the scope:

```
@if(something)
{
     Html.Hidden("InputID", model.Field)
}
```

**Edit 1**

However, if you have a HTML tag between your previous "@operator {" you should use the @ again on the following instruction.

```
 @if(something)
{
     <div>
          @Html.Hidden("InputID", model.Field)   
          //now you need to use the @ again due the <div> tag
     </div>
}
```